# Spring neo4j fails to find property by value when using repository

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

given the following entity:

```
@NodeEntity  
public final class Foo  
{    
        @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Indexed
    private String name;
}
```

repository:

```
public interface FooRepository extends GraphRepository<Foo> {}
```

service:

```
@Service  
public class FooService  
{  
     @Autowired  FooRepository fooRepo;  
     public List<Foo> searchFor() {  
        EndResult<Foo> results = fooRepo.findAllByPropertyValue("name","*");  
                results.size();       //no results  
     }  

}
```

I am relying on the function that resides in the `IndexRepository` because I want to leverage the Lucene lookups.  However, the above query is failing to return anything.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use wildcards with the *findAllByPropertyValue* method. Maybe use the *findAllByQuery* method where can you use them. Your query could be as simple as:

```
name:*
```

Comment: I agree it should be that simple.  I am trying to force it into a Lucene lookup.

Answer (score 0):

> I agree it should be that simple. I am trying to force it into a Lucene lookup

If I understand what you want, can you not query the index directly?

```
@Autowired 
Neo4jTemplate fooTemplate;
...
fooTemplate.getIndex(Foo.class).query("name:*");
```

This should do the same as adding a

```
@Query("start n=node:fooIndex(name=*)")
Set<Foo> getAllFoos();
```

to your `FooRepository`.